# Error SSIS OLE DB Source Editor

Tags: sql, ssis

i got a problem.. i dont know what to do anymore.. I want to add a query on OLE DB Source from DataFlow and when i try to click on Columns(after i put the query) i got this error>> :

**Error at Data Flow Task[OLE DB Source[31]]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E14.
An OLE DB record is avaliable. Source "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0" Hresult: 0x80040E14
Description: "Statement(s) coult not be prepared".
An OLE DB record is avaliable. Source "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0" Hresult: 0x80040E14
Description: "Invalid object name '#tmp33'.".**

**Additional information:
Exception from HRESULT: 0xC0202009 (Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap)**

I tryed to search on internet about those error, and nothing.. nothing what could help me... If u know something about those errors please help me!

Thnx stackoverflow!

Answer (score 1):

On your connection manager for your ole db source set DelayValidation = True and RetainSameConnection = True. The issue appears to be the use of a temp table. For one it doesn't exist already so your query is failing validation. RetainSameConnection will ensure that if you have other flows that they can see this temp table.